# What is the origin of the phrase "Put one in the wood for him"?

Tags: phrase-origin

I'm curious about the origin of the phrase "(Put) one in the wood (for him)" meaning ‘reserve a pint of beer to give him when he arrives’.
I live in west Kent, UK and hear this phrase fairly often.
[This](http://www.sirc.org/publik/ptpchap4.html) is the only reference I found.

Comment: Yes, that link does note that the suffix ".. in the wood" is local to Kent. Maybe it's metaphorical, as in "draw a pint, and stick the glass behind the [wooden] bar for when Bob shows up later"?

Answer (score 2):

"Put one in the wood" is a competitive dart throwing term. The bullseye is made of wood while the outer board target regions are made of other material such as horsehair.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually *put one in the **barrel***...

> *I asked the landlord for a pint, pointing at Duncan. He pointed at two full ones lined up at Duncan's elbow but agreed to [put one in the barrel](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to%20put%20one%20in%20the%20barrel%20for%20him%22) for him.*

Admittedly it's a slightly odd usage, in that the pint of beer is *already* in the barrel, so *reserve* might be a better verb than *put*. I'm from Sussex, and I note OP is in Kent, so perhaps the *pint / wood / barrel* form is essentially a South East UK usage (but it's probably more widespread).

I don't think there's any reason to look to an "origin" as such. If your friend arrives at the pub after you, you might say *"There's a pint in the barrel"* (already paid for by you). Americans don't drink pints, but I'm sure if one was eating a slice of pie in a diner he could say *"There's a slice behind the counter [for you]"* when his friend arrived, and expect to be understood.

---

Here's a link to sociolinguist Kate Fox in [*Watching the English* (2005)](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Watching_the_English/tNZfLeHSFvQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22put+one+in+the+wood+for%22&pg=PT127&printsec=frontcover) talking about it.

Comment: Sure we drink pints. Sure we do. We just don't call them that ;)

Comment: Thank you. I've never heard of "put one in the barrel" myself. But I did think my original phrase "put one in the wood" that often shortened to "one in the wood" may allude to a beer cask. Traditionally they were made of wood. And if "put" could mean "to leave it there" in the cask until it's asked for.

Comment: @Dan: Brits drink pints of warm beer stored in (wooden) barrels. American drink bottles of cold beer stored in fridges, but I don't think *There's a bottle in the fridge [for you]* would normally be understood to mean *...paid for by me earlier*. On the other hand, I'm pretty sure I've heard *behind the counter* used with that sense in American movies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers American bars offer both bottled and draft beer. The draft beer is warm. Outside a Belgian sour, I'm not much one for beer (liquor is quicker!), but my beer snob friends tend to say draft is preferred, if you can get it.

Comment: Most American "draft" beers are infused with nitrogen to facilitate pumping, which makes it very fizzy :(  British "real" beer on the other hand is brought up with a hydraulic pump, and is not fizzy but flat.  Sometimes in the US you might find a "cask condition" beer that doesn't get nitrogenized, but I've yet to find an American artisan beer in a British style that has the mouthfeel and subtle nutty notes and mild hops of the beer I was served in the rural pubs in Somerset in days of yore.

Comment: Real ale isn't flat @TRomano, it's just not fizzy, there is a difference. Beer that's been standing in a glass long enough to go flat is pretty horrible. Southern pubs tend to serve beer without any froth on top but up north we prefer it with a nice head. Just one of those nice regional differences.

Comment: @BoldBen: Agreed. It hasn't "gone flat".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are you just dangling brit-bait with the 'warm beer' trope?

Comment: @Spagirl: Not really. In fact, even if we exclude lagers, probably *most* "beer" served in UK pubs is in fact cooled to some extent, so strictly speaking my assertion isn't actually true. But if my late-arriving friend asked *What barrel?* when I said *There's one in the barrel for you*, I'd still say *The beer barrel **behind the counter*** even though almost certainly said barrel would actually be down in the cool cellar (plus the supply pipes might be wrapped in stuff to insulate or cool even more).

Comment: Despite having downed umpty pints in dozens of English pubs in the past 50 years I've never once heard that phrase, nor anything greatly like it.

At a guess, "put one in the wood" might mean "pay for one in the barrel" and I suggest that's based solely on the result, not any detail about the method.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: This Q was a few years ago now. But I've just searched for the quoted string [**"put one in the wood for"**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22put+one+in+the+wood+for%22), and I see the second result is from Kate Fox's *Watching the English* - which I bought and read last year. She says it's *a local version of a more common pubtalk expression, meaning 'reserve a pint of beer to give him when he arrives, which I will pay for now' (The more usual phrase is 'Put one in for . . .' or 'Leave one in for . . .*

Comment: ...and I know she knows what she's talking about, because she goes on to talk about when you offer the barman a drink, and he says *Thanks very much. I'll put that by for Ron.* As a wayward teenager cadging cigarettes, I remember that after successfully bumming ***one***, I might cheekily ask *Can I have another one for Ron?* (if they asked "Who's Ron", the answer would of course be ***Later** On!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've no idea why SE threw it up now… Logically, of course it should mean something like 'reserve a pint of beer to give him when he arrives, which I will pay for now', more usually 'Put /leave one in for…" but what provenance is that?

Isn't the point what "local version" it might be, if any?

Isn't Kate Fox's barman saying 'Thanks very much. I'll put that by for Ron' a very different expression? Same for the wayward teenager cadging cigarettes…

Comment: The provenance of *one in the wood* obviously derives from *one in the [wooden] **barrel***. But here's a recent instance of a squaddie saying [*I ordered a can of Tiger beer from the bar and **put one in the wood** for the mess president.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22put+one+in+the+wood+for+the+mess+president%22) where it seems unlikely there's even a barrel anyway (he's in the officers' mess, where they probably only have bottled beer! :) I take *that* citation as evidence that the usage is still alive and kicking!

Answer (score 0):

I think "one in the wood" is a Kent/ south east thing.

In Kent you can say I'll have a Stella and "one in the wood" and be understood no problem. Say it elsewhere and you'll get blank stares. But it means you got one behind bar ready when you are. (Bar=wood).

I used to work as a barman when I was around 20 and used to drink in the same pub and used to rack up loads of pints in the wood from people buying drinks for the staff. Got 18 pints in the wood.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but ELU doesn't usually use on-line abbreviations (e.g., u for you); and you've got a couple of misspellings there too (and failure to capitalize).  Are the drinks behind the bar actually poured, or just available to be served?

Comment: I think the figurative reference is to the wooden ***beer barrel***, not the bar itself.